# SSRS date filter

Tags: reporting-services, filter, report, builder

I have a farely simple tablix:

```
Year   |  Trimester  |  Measure    
2016         T1          12    
2016         T2          8    
2015         T1          16    
2015         T2          5    
2015         T3          8    
2015         T4          13
```

I'm going nuts trying to come up with a filter which would filter out last year's trimesters that did not yet come to pass this year. Example: I'm at the end of T2 of 2016, so when I generate the tablix, I only want:

```
Year   |  Trimester  |  Measure   
2016         T1          12    
2016         T2          8    
2015         T1          16    
2015         T2          5
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could define date ranges for each trimester and run the filter against the corresponding date ranges when filtering by trimesters.  You may need an array of trimester date ranges if the actual dates vary from year to year.  Each year could be represented by a class which holds the trimester date ranges for that year and each year would be one item in the array.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes the dates vary and at this point, I don't know what dates it will be in 2 years, plus the months slightly overlap, so I cant even use Month() to isolate my trimesters. But I have tried the following option: T1 is financial period (FP) 1-2-3, T2 is 4-5-6, T3 is 7,8,9,10 and T4 is 11,12,13. I tried working my way with Today() vs Fields!FP.Value but it doesn't recognize the FP as a date...